# Calculating the total time by adding the time intervals

Tags: php

I have got the verious time intervals in H:i:s format like shown below:

```
$interval1 = 12:15:33;
$interval2 = 0:36:10;
$interval3 = 0:1:30;
```

Now i want to add all this intervals together like

```
 $total = $interval1 +  $interval2 +  $interval3;
```

Here is my php code

```
function addinterval($x,$y){
    $x = explode(':', $x);
    $y = explode(':', $y);
    $seconds = $minit = $hours = 0;

    $seconds = $x[2] + $y[2];
    if($seconds > 60){
        $seconds = $seconds - 60;
        $minit = $minit + 1;
    }
    $minit = $minit + $x[1] + $y[1];
    if($minit > 60){
        $minit = $minit - 60;
        $hours = $hours + 1;
    }
    $hours = $hours +  $x[0] + $y[0];
    return $hours. ':' . $mint . ':' . $seconds;

}



$first = addinterval('12:15:33','0:36:10');
echo 'The result :' . $first;
$second = addinterval($first, '0:1:30');
echo 'The final result' . $second;
```

Comment: can you please display your output or you want your output to be

Comment: Don't do this stuff for your own... I prefer http://carbon.nesbot.com/

Comment: These intervals are part of date timestamps (H:i:s) or just times (like laps) which you want to sum (hh:mm:ss)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function getSeconds($interval)
{
    list($h, $m, $s) = explode(':', $interval);

    return $h * 3600 + $m * 60 + $s;
}

echo date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime(date('Y-m-d 00:00:00')) + getSeconds($interval1) + getSeconds($interval2) + getSeconds($interval3));
```

It will be good working when sum of intervals more than one current day.

[Demo](https://eval.in/555283).

Answer (score 3):

Use `strtotime()`.

```
$interval1 = "12:15:33";
$interval2 = "0:36:10";
$interval3 = "0:1:30";

$interval2Sec = strtotime($interval2)-strtotime("00:00:00");
$interval3Sec = strtotime($interval3)-strtotime("00:00:00");

$total = strtotime($interval1) + $interval2Sec + $interval3Sec;
echo $time =date("Y-m-d h:i:s", $total);
```

**Output**

```
2016-04-18 12:53:13
```

**Online Demo : [Click Here](https://eval.in/555320)**

Comment: but it returns the value into the current time

Comment: please show us your desire output. I will convert it and edit my code accordingly.

Comment: It's the good way, subtract the total by `strtotime("today")`.  ` $total = (strtotime($interval1) +  strtotime($interval2) +  ($interval3))-strtotime("today");`

Comment: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/874ed2d6b7b35566506e99ae3b3fae74de816938 working example

Comment: i have added the code which is not returning the result. the answer i want is `12:53:13`

Comment: Missed `strtotime($interval3)`

Comment: it works good for intervals in one day. This case: $interval1 = "12:15:33"; $interval2 = "00:36:10"; $interval3 = "11:59:30"; will return time of current day, but it should be tomorrow.

Comment: Please check edited code. Its easy and more useful for your current attached code as you have define already one function using this code you no need to create another function. Also work with all day and time. @abhishek bagul

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do this is most likely to use strtotime to convert them to timestamps and then do the adding together:

```
$o = strtotime($interval1)+strtotime($interval2)+strtotime($interval3);
```